# Can't resize emacs window after setting it during start up

Tags: emacs, window

I'm using emacs and setting my window size at start up using the code

```
;;make window take up full height of display.
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist `(fullscreen . fullheight))
```

Which works as expected. However, I can no longer change the window height after the fact using the cursor.  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maximize` instead of `fullscreen`.

```
;; 1st frame
(toggle-frame-maximized)
;; other frames
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but do I use this with the 'add-to-list... syntax?  Won't this affect the frame width as well?

Comment: Unfortunately even `(toggle-frame-maximized)` breaks the window sizing for me (dragging the edges does nothing). I've resorted to having Emacs start up as a small window, and enlarging via Rectangle mac app